# The change in column space after reducing a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

When a matrix **A** is reduced to **R**, its column space might change. However, the dimension of the column space does not change(same number of pivots).

Why is this so? Is there a way to understand this geometrically? For a matrix of rank 2 in **R**^3, does it mean the subspace (the plane where the vectors lie in) remains as a plane, but the orientation of the plane changes?

Comment: The columns of $A$ are vectors that span the column space. When you row reduce a matrix, you are changing those vectors.

Comment: So the vectors change, but the place where combinations of those vectors can end up in(the column space) does not?

Comment: I don't understand that comment at all. But a row operation is a manipulation of the coordinate positions. You don't change the dependence/independence of the vectors when you do this, but you are changing where they are in space.